# How can i change VoiceOver's pronunciation of my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, voiceover, cfbundledisplayname

When VoiceOver is on, i'd like to control the way my app is pronounced. For example, if my app is named "**BLOT**" , currently pronounced "**BLAUGHT**" - my desired pronounciation would be "**BLOAT**". I'is this possible?
I've did my research and found that there are ways to control the characters via *CFBundleDisplayName* on `Infoplist.strings`, but havent found anything that fits my particular need. any ideas?

Comment: I would add the question should include locale. Different languages will have different phonetics even if the app name is not localized.

Answer (score 5):

As of iOS 8 and OS X 10.10, you can use the [`CFBundleSpokenName`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/plist/info/CFBundleSpokenName) Info.plist key to achieve what you want.

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I need, but on iOS 8.3 it seems to have no effect. Any trick to getting this working besides adding it to the plist? --Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given that my Radar (14077202) asking for a way to do this is still open, I believe you cannot.

Therefore, the only way to do so is to file your own bug with Apple (bugreport.apple.com) and wait for them to provide such a feature.